# base64_encode image failed to open stream when coming through AJAX request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, base64

I have a blog which displays a bunch of pictures. To minimize server requests I am encoding each one of the images to base64 using a simple PHP function.

I have an infinite scroll feature on my blog which uses AJAX to send a request to the server to get more blogs on page scroll.

The issue here is when the base64 encoded image comes through the AJAX request, I get the error `[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

The base64 encoded images are showing up perfectly when they are not coming through the ajax call..

Here is the PHP function I am using to convert to base64:

```
// convert images to base64 for image URIs
function base64Data($sFile) {                   

    // Switch to right MIME-type
    $sExt = strtolower(substr(strrchr($sFile, '.'), 1));

    // trim the first forward slash from the images
    if(strpos($sFile, '/', 1)) {
        $sFile = ltrim($sFile, '/');
    }


    switch($sExt)
    {
        case 'gif':
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'png':
            $sMimeType = 'image/'. $sExt;
        break;

        case 'ico':
            $sMimeType = 'image/x-icon';
        break;

        case 'eot':
            $sMimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject';
        break;

        case 'otf':
        case 'ttf':
        case 'woff':
            $sMimeType = 'application/octet-stream';
        break;

        default:
            exit('Invalid extension file!');
    }

    $sBase64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($sFile));
    return "data:$sMimeType;base64,$sBase64";
}
```

The image paths are stored in my mysql database like so `/uploads/blogs/images/imagefile.jpg` that is why I am using `ltrim()` to trim that first slash. Without it, `file_get_contents()` doesn't work anywhere.

Comment: Try adding a `var_dump($sFile)` or some other method of debugging the actual path, the error will probably become obvious when you see what $sFile is.

Comment: it seems that the location of $sFile is not provided correctly, echo $sFile or find the correction location of $sFile

Comment: if `$sFile` isn't provided correctly then why do the other images show up correctly when not coming through AJAX?

Comment: this is what I get for the images that are showing up correctly `string(65) "uploads/blogs/photos/e0bb0ac484aa4b3c9cfad509eac1c5f93d9e9397.jpg"` and this is what I get for the images not showing up correctly `Warning: file_get_contents(uploads/blogs/photos/24c94e5fff96ea2c9a2e525e99bcd31d52f505a4.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /beta/classes/string.class.php on line 91
string(65) "uploads/blogs/photos/24c94e5fff96ea2c9a2e525e99bcd31d52f505a4.jpg"`

Comment: This clearly shown the error.

Comment: ...ok, so what is it? I clearly can't see it.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj can you point out the error to me? I don't understand what is happening...

Comment: "Warning: file_get_contents(uploads/blogs/photos/24c94e5fff96ea2c9a2e525e99bcd31d52f505a4.‌​jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /beta/classes/string.class.php on line 91" this is self explained.

Answer (score 0):

"Warning: file_get_contents(uploads/blogs/photos/24c94e5fff96ea2c9a2e525e99bcd31d52f505a4.‌​‌​jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /beta/classes/string.class.php on line 91" this is self explained. If you are sure that file exists at that path. Then try to use absolute path for file instead of relative in string.class.php which may be one of reason file path is not getting.